# Using an async function on useEffect that has as an argument a State that's also async setted

Tags: reactjs

I'm not sure how to title this question, please feel free to edit it.

I'm consuming an api that supplies projects (uniquely related to a login/password) and a list of status related to the tasks of those projects. It has two routes:

- project route: receives a `login` and a `password` and returns its id and name:

```js
{idProject: string, nome: string}
```

- status route: receives an `idProject` and returns an array of its status

```js
[{idStatus: string, area: string, descricao: string}]
```

I know mixing languages and not using a token is a very bad practice but i'm not the one coding the backend, i'm just consuming it. Since I'm using typescript, I decided not to translate the variables names otherwise types would mess up, I'm sorry about it.

I created a `services.tsx` to consume it:

```js
import axios from "axios";

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: "", // omitted for safety reasons
});

export const getUserPromise = async (login: string, password: string) => {
  const userPromise = api.get(`/projetos?login=${login}&senha=${password}`);
  return userPromise;
};

export const getAllStatusPromise = async (idProjeto: string) => {
  const AllStatusPromise = api.get(`/projetos/${idProjeto}/statusAreas`);
  return AllStatusPromise;
};
```

My `App.tsx` defines functions `getUser()` and `getAllStatus()`, for handeling the promises and storing them in `user` and `allStatus` states.

It also defines an async `getRequests()` function, that's used on `useEffect()` for `await` calling `getUser()`and `getAllStatus()`.

It also prints the results on the html:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getUserPromise, getAllStatusPromise } from "./services";

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    idProjeto: "0000",
    nome: "Fallback User",
  });

  const [allStatus, setAllStatus] = useState([
    {
      idStatus: "0000",
      area: "Fallback AllStatus",
      descricao: "Fallback allStatus",
    },
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getRequests();
  }, []);

  const getRequests = async () => {
    const mocked_login = ""; // Omitted for safety reasons
    const mocked_password = ""; // Omitted for safety reasons

    await getUser(mocked_login, mocked_password);
    await getAllStatus(user.idProjeto);
  };

  const getUser = async (login: string, password: string) => {
    try {
      const userPromise = await getUserPromise(login, password);
      const user = userPromise.data;
      setUser(user);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const getAllStatus = async (idProjeto: string) => {
    try {
      const allStatusPromise = await getAllStatusPromise(idProjeto);
      const allStatus = allStatusPromise.data;
      setAllStatus(allStatus);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        user.nome: {user.nome} | user.idProjeto: {user.idProjeto}
      </p>
      <p>Number of status: {allStatus.length}</p>
      {allStatus.map((status) => {
        return (
          <ul>
            Status:
            <li>status.area: {status.area}</li>
            <li>status.descricao: {status.descricao}</li>
            <li>status.idStatus: {status.idStatus}</li>
          </ul>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I'm using `user` state as an argument for `getAllStatus()`.

The piece of code works:

[image]

`user` was successfully set when rendering the page: user related to my mocked login and password has `projectId === 12345`.

However, `allStatus` does not have the expected values. It requested the fallback `projectId` 0000, which returns 63 status on the api. However, `projecId` 12345 does not have 63 status. It has only 5.

That means something is wrong with my async calls. `user.projectId` state is not set to `1245` when `getAllStatus()` is called. But it's when the page's rendered, that's why the rendering user works but the sequential call for `getAllStatus` don't.

How do I force `getAllStatus()` to wait for the state changing in `getUser()` to be finished?

Comment: I'm 100% sure user is not setted when getAllStatus is called. I console.logged between the calls in getRequests and it prints the fallback user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useState sometimes does not change state immediately. In your case, you can return user and get it in your getRequests function.

```
const getRequests = async () => {
    const mocked_login = ""; // Omitted for safety reasons
    const mocked_password = ""; // Omitted for safety reasons

    const user = await getUser(mocked_login, mocked_password); // get the returned user
    await getAllStatus(user.idProjeto);
  };

  const getUser = async (login: string, password: string) => {
    try {
      const userPromise = await getUserPromise(login, password);
      const user = userPromise.data;
      setUser(user);
      return user;    // return it here
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);    

    }
  };
```

Comment: Thank you a lot!! I don't think that exact variable name will work since it's already storing my state, and typescript will probably scream about a function that returns a user or null, but i'll fix it and try it! If it works i'll pick your answer

Comment: IT WORKED I LOVE YOU